# Подсказки мест Places API for Android

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, google-maps-api, google-places-api

Не получается собрать из примера проект. Android 4.2
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete?hl=ru
Беру разметку.

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
  />
```

Получаю ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее идём в MainActivity.

```
***Java***
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
        Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
    }
  });
_____________________________________________________________________
***Kotlin***
val autocompleteFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment) as PlaceAutocompleteFragment
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object:PlaceSelectionListener() {
  fun onPlaceSelected(place:Place) {
    // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
    Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName())
  }
  fun onError(status:Status) {
    // TODO: Handle the error.
    Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status)
  }
})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А тут что импортировать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут пытался курить.Но тщетно.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html?hl=ru#using-apis

Прикладываю скрины билдов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Рабочий вариант, проверял на физическом устройстве. При вводе в строку поиска предлагает различные места. Скриншоты рабочие.
[image: Окно][image: Окно][image: Окно][image: Окно][image: Окно]
На статус импортировать библиотеку.

> import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status

## MainActivity

Тут появились новые "import" и "Log" временно убран.

```
package autocomplete.autocompletenew

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
import android.util.Log
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceSelectionListener


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val autocompleteFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment) as PlaceAutocompleteFragment

        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object : PlaceSelectionListener {
            override fun onPlaceSelected(place: Place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
               // Log.i(FragmentActivity.TAG, "Place: " + place.name)
            }

            override fun onError(status: Status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
               // Log.i(FragmentActivity.TAG, "An error occurred: " + status)
            }
        })

    }
}
```

## acitity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="autocomplete.autocompletenew.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

## build-проекта

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

## build-приложения

Тут появились 2 строчки:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
>   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "autocomplete.autocompletenew"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```